# How to show this equation using Dirichlet formulas and Riemann-Lebesgue lemma?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Using the Dirichlet formulas and Riemann-Lebesgue lemma how to show following equation? ( $\forall \varepsilon >0 $)

$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\int _{0}^{\varepsilon }\dfrac {\sin \left( \left( 2n+1\right) t\right) } {\sin \left( t\right) }dt=\dfrac {\pi } {2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If the $\sin t$ in the denominator were replaced by $t,$ the integral would become

$$\int_0^\epsilon\frac{\sin((2n+1)t)}{t}\, dt = \int_0^{(2n+1)\epsilon}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\, dt \to \frac{\pi}{2}.$$